# MVC best practices for when to load partial views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a web application which has the same banner on every page with links etc. What I want to know, when one of these links is clicked, should I simply use javascript/jquery as follows to render a partial view of the content into a div... or just do a regular Html.ActionLink where the target page contains the banner?

page structure

```
<div id ="banner">
// banner content
</div>
<div id="mainContentDiv">
// changing content
</div>
```

So when I select a link in my banner where the banner doesn't change, should I call some jquery function to change the content...

```
$('#mainContentDiv').load('/ControllerName/ActionName?args...');
```

... which would call some controller action and return a partial view in my main content div. Is this good practice? It means I am only loading content needed and not having to reload my banner. I've played around with trying to return partial views using json also but it seems overcomplicated for what I am doing. So my question is... is this the right way to carry out this operation or are there any disadvantages doing this?

It's just at the minute I have everything as Html.ActionLink, so it's probably more a question of, is it worth a refactor to keep the static content not requiring the refresh... it would mean the user can't see where each link is taking them (as it would all be javascript onclick events, and I would have to change all my action methods to return partial views (as well as removing the banner from my my current views and making them partial views...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, why not [do both](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)? I'll try to outline one possible approach:

First, you have your link `<a data-target="#main" href="/users/1/show">Show me user 1!</a>`. So at this point we have a normal link that works for everyone - humans and search engines alike.

Now to jazz it up.

```
$("a").click(function() {
  var target = $.data(this, "target");
  $(target).load("_" + this.href);
  return false;
});
```

By convention I name my partials with underscores. This is a very basic demo, you can do other fancy stuff but this is the general idea.

Comment: I like this. Good link as well.

Answer (score -2):

When to load partial views?

when making an ajax call like ajax.actionlink